# How do portfolio software generate their portfolio suggestions so quickly when the possibilities are huge?

Tags: algorithm, math, statistics, finance, portfolio

I hope this does not get closed because it is related to algorithms that I have not been able to figure out(its also pretty long because I'm so confused about how its being done).  Basically many years back I used to work at a mutual fund and we used different tools to select optimize portfolios as well as hedge existing ones.  We would take these results and make our own modifications then sell them to clients.  After my company downsized, I decided I wanted to give it a try(to create the software and include my customizations) but I have no clue how combinations are actually generated for the software.

After 6 months of trying, I'm accepting that my approach is impossible.  I was trying to use combination algorithms like from Knuth's book, as well as doing `bit` combinations to try to find every possible portfolio(I limited it to 30 stocks) on the NYSE(5,000+ stocks). But as per everyone I have spoken to this will take me billions of billions of years to just get one days results(for me on a GPU i stopped it after 2 days of straight processing).

So what am I missing? We would enter our risk tolerance and view of the market(stock market growth expectations, inflation expectations, fed funds expectations,etc..) and it would give us the ideal portfolio(in theory..) within a few seconds/minutes. With thousands of possibilities and quadrillion possible combinations of weights of stocks, how are they able to calculate results so quickly(or even at all)? As the admin of the system, I know we downloaded a file everyday(less than 100 mb and loaded in a mssql database probably just market data..so its not like we had every possibility. Using my approach above I would get a 5 gig file in a min of doing my version of Knuth's combination algo) and the applications worked offline(so it must have been doing it locally on the desktop/laptop cpu not on a massive supercomputer somewhere and took a min or two to run..15 minutes was the longest for a global fund which includes every stock in the world). Its so confusing because their work required correlation of the entire fund(I don't think they were just sending the top stocks they pre-calculated because everyone got different results). So if I wanted a 30 stock fund that gave me 2% returns and had a negative correlation with the market, and was 60% hedged how could the software generate that portfolio out of billions of possibilities so quickly? note, I'm not asking about the math or the finance part, I'm asking how it was able to generate 30 stocks from the entire market that gave 2% returns when in order to do that it would need to know the returns of all 30 stock portfolio(That alone would make it run for billions of years, right? the other restrictions make it more complex).

So How is this being done programmatically? I'm starting to believe they are not using Knuth's combination algorithm to generate every possibility yet their results don't seem randomly selected and individually selecting the stocks seems to miss the correlation part.  How can so many investment softwares do things like this?

Comment: This is a open-source and ready for use portfolio-analyzer tool that can be improved and add a desired extra functionality that you need: [Java portfolio-analyzer tool](https://github.com/zappee/portfolio-analyzer). You can consider this project as a nice base project to extend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Such algorithms almost certainly don't generate every possibility - as you rightly observe that would be impractical.

Portfolio selection is however very easy to do with other techniques that will give you a very good answer. The two most likely are:

- If you make simplifying assumptions around risk / return you can solve for an optimal portfolio mathematically (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capital_asset_pricing_model for some of the maths)
- A genetic algorithm which does mutation / crossover operations on randomised sample portfolios will find a very good solution pretty fast. You can combine this with Monte-Carlo style modelling approaches to understand the range of possible outcomes.

Personally, I'd probably suggest the genetic algorithm approach - although it's not as mathematically pure, it will give you good answers and should able to handle any constraints you want to throw at it quite easily (e.g. max number of stocks in a portfolio)

Comment: Thanks for the answer(after realizing 6 months of work on combinational algorithms could not achieve it, that was my semi-rant).  I am going to spend the night reading up on genetic algorithms but how do they overcome the problem of finding the right portfolio? For example, you say you want a 30 stock portfolio that has 3% returns. First it needs to find 30 stocks, then it needs to figure 3% returns(which is worst than the 30 combo problem because have negative returning stocks that mute the returns of higher returning stocks.A +5% with a -2% would give you the return).

Comment: I'm sorry if I am not getting it, but wouldn't the genetic algorithm will have to some how overcome that problem?  If they just do a few then they maybe not getting the optimal returns, right?

Comment: You have to define an objective function for the genetic algorithm. Presumably if you wanted 3% returns you actually mean "as close to 3% returns as possible with minimum variance". So you might define an objective function as `-(return - 3%)^2 - (k * variance)` for some constant k, and evolve solutions to maximise that value

Comment: I understood the objectives and the traits for crossover, but wouldn't it still come across about the same problem I did in which the possibilities are beyond its ability to calculate? For example, running your example above would provide several billion portfolios. I'm confused there, if its capturing a subset of the actual results then how do you know its a representational subset? couldn't it just kick back the first 100 matches when the nyse would have more actual results & the other results maybe better?

Comment: @Error_404 - I suggest you read up on genetic algorithms. You would produce perhaps 10,000 generations of maybe 100 portfolios in each. Each generation would hopefully be a (minor) improvement on the one before. That would probably be enough to evolve a pretty good portfolio.

Answer (score 2):

Modern Portfolio theory is a subject in its own right, with books such as "Modern Portfolio Theory and Investment Analysis", and an introduction at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modern_portfolio_theory.

One way to get problems you can actually solve is to treat it as a mathematical optimization problem. If you have a vector which gives you the amount of each stock you buy, then - under various assumptions - the return is a linear function of this vector, and the risk is a quadratic function of this vector. Maximising the return for given risk, or minimising the risk for given return, is a well-understood mathematical problem, even for very large numbers of stocks - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_programming.

One practical problem with this is that the answer you get will probably tell you buy some fraction of almost all the stocks on the market. My guess is that real life programs use some "secret sauce" heuristic that doesn't guarantee the perfect answer, subject to a constraint on the number of stocks you are actually prepared to buy, but works pretty well in practice. Returning the perfect answer appears to be a hard problem - see e.g. http://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1105/1105.3594.pdf